# Mount ZFS dataset in unprivileged containers

Tags: mount, permissions, lxc, zfs

First a bit of information about my configuration:

- Ubuntu 15.10
- ZFS pool created
- LXC containers stored in pool/lxc
- Dataset created in `pool/mydataset` owned by `user1`

Now I need one of the containers to access the files/folders in `pool/mydataset`. I tried the following:

- Created a user `user1` inside the container
- Edited `pool/lxc/mycontainer/config` and added:

  ```
  lxc.mount.entry = /pool/mydataset mnt/mydataset none rw,bind 0 0
  ```

When I start the container the dataset is mounted, but `ls -la /mnt/mydataset` in the container shows `nobody:nogroup` instead of `user1:user1`, which means all files are read-only.

Any idea how to get the correct permissions in the mounted directory?

Answer (score 4):

If indeed `mycontainer` is unprivileged, then its owner might not have access to the path `/pool/mydataset`. Users in unprivileged containers have their uid offset on the host by the container-owner uid, so `user1` inside the container isn't the same as `user1` on the host.

1. You can check what user on the host owns the container with `sudo ls -l /pool/lxc | grep mycontainer` (`sudo` might not be required, depending on `/pool/lxc`'s permissions, but `ls` should be safe enough to run as root either way. Going forward, omit `sudo` where desirable if permissions make that possible). For example, I get

   ```
   drwxr-xr-x 4 100000 100000    5 Apr 22 11:37 mycontainer
   ```

   showing that the uid and gid of the container's owner is 100000 (we see a uid instead of a name since the user doesn't exist on the host).
2. Test `/pool/mydataset`'s permissions with `sudo ls -l /pool | grep mydataset` (or `sudo ls -l /pool/mydataset` for its contents).

   If you want the files to be writable from within the container, you just have to make sure whichever user inside `mycontainer` you want to be able to write to `/pool/mydataset` has permissions to do so on the host. E.g., `root` on `mycontainer` has uid 100000 on host, and if `user1` in `mycontainer` has uid 1001 (test with `id user1` *from within the container*) then on the host its uid would be 101001.

---

You might do that by allowing everyone on the host to write to `/pool/mydataset` with

```
sudo chmod -R o+w /pool/mydataset
```

(note: this will add permissions recursively inside `/pool/mydataset`), or perhaps better to make sure users in group `user1` have write permissions (set it recursively with `sudo chmod -R g+w /pool/mydataset` if not), then add the owner of the container to group `user1` with

```
sudo usermod -a -G user1 <username>
```

(In my case above, we saw that no user on the host owns the container, so we should first create a user with uid and gid 100000 with

```
adduser --no-create-home --uid 100000 --disabled-password --disabled-login <username>
```

Of course, you might wish to give permissions only to `user1` inside the container, so create a user with its *host* uid and add that to group `user1` on host, e.g., 101001.)

You can also go nuclear and give ownership of `/pool/mydataset` to `mycontainer`'s root with

```
sudo chown -R 100000:100000 /pool/mydataset
```

but that could mess with other users on host accessing the data.

---

Once you've done that, the mount you set should allow write permissions inside `mycontaier`, as desired.